# It is possible for the nodes of a network to have a different total cost. If they have the same value in degree centrality?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, network

I do same simulations with randoms networks and for each network and calculates different measures such degree centrality. In the network is likely more than one node to have the highest degree value. For the calculation i used the adjacency matrix.

For these nodes I calculate the total cost and I use the following code.

```
for n = 1  : num_nodes
    % u is the node have the highest degree value 
    [distanse,~] = dijkstra(treeAdj_from_adj,n,u);
    Cost_of_median_tree = Cost_of_median_tree + (distanse * weight_of_vertex(u));

end
```

This is my results from my simulation of degree centrality :

```
# RC    Time_execuson    Total_Cost     Posision_of_node    Time*Cost
0.250000     0.000399       466.000000         59           0.186120
0.250000     0.000399       471.000000         85           0.188117
0.250000     0.000399       461.000000         164           0.184123
0.250000     0.000399       476.000000         189           0.190114
0.250000     0.000399       472.000000         195           0.188516
0.250000     0.000399       477.000000         198           0.190513
```

Nobody knows if the nodes have different total cost???

Comment: It is quite hard to understand what is the problem you are having and answer your question due to missing context and details.

Comment: what I forgot to say that weight_of_vertex is a table who has in all his positions the value 1. Τhen the total cost should not be the same in these nodes (59,85...198)? @dtldarek